# Windows Phone 8 data transfer on between pages

Tags: windows-phone-8, data-transfer

I am trying to transfer data on between pages. And I am writting below code. PivotPage.xaml.cs code;

```
if (Convert.ToDouble(PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["futbol"]) != null)
   futbol = Convert.ToDouble(PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["futbol"]);
else
   futbol = 0.0;
```

User can select or not select "*futbol*". If selected "*futbol*" not problem. But If not selected "*futbol*" give an error.

Error: An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

How can I using "Current.State" or another function?

Thanks in advance. (sorry my language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the "futbol" is present in the State collection.

```
futbol = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey("futbol")
    ? Convert.ToDouble(PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["futbol"])
    : 0.0;
```

Also, feel free to read this article on [different ways of storing data on Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361.aspx)